# Помогите с книгой по Ruby

Tags: ruby, книги

Знаю что темы уже заезжены. Хочу просто свежий совет.
Можете посоветовать ОЧЕНЬ хорошую книгу чисто по Ruby желательно только на Русском языке, пока не могу вникать в аглийский язык. Учу его что бы правильно давать имена пременным.

### Цель от книги

*получить знания которые помогут:*

- Писать правильный код для работы с API других сервисов.

***Например**: написать какую нибудь библиотеку которую потом можно легко чуть доработать и использовать для работы с другим сервисом у котоорогоо тоже есть своё API, создать своего рода некий базовый шаблон от которого потом идти дальше.*

- правильно структурировать файлы, каждый файл в соответствующей папке
- научится писать свои парсеры различной информации в интернете, собирать контент, чистить его регулярками или иными способами, отправлять в базу данных предварительно удалённо соединившись в другим сервисом
- работать с CRON
- различных демонов писать
- научиться работать в потоками
- использование Ajax

### Подбор материала основываясь на своих предпочтениях

Вообще я люблю создавать сайты на разные темы:
*Женщины, блоги, кино, мультфильмы, автомобили, и т.д и*
Но мне хочется научиться автоматизировать свои действия потому что бывает зачастую попадаются моменты однотипной работы которая отнимает не 1 час.
***Например*** вот я сейчас задумал создать сайт новостей:

- есть идеи
- готовая оптимизация
- создан макет шаблона

Но вот собирать каждую нвоость в интернете и публиковать её себе было бы наверное как минимум глупо, а если вы например ещё и захотите сами писать уникальные статьи для них то тогда можно попращаться со сном и жизнью раз и на всегда.

Отличным выходом из ситуации было бы написать свой скрипт который бы работал в автономном режиме и потихоньку неспеша без доса собирал бы информацию с паутины, формировал бы данные в формати например JSON и потом отправлял бы всё в базу данных, а от туда уже шёл бы ещё какой нибудь запрос на какой нибудь сайт занимающийся написанием уникальных текстов например text.ru и благодаря их API я бы мог там программно создавать запросы на написание того или иного текста, ну и потом уже всё публикуется на сайте или как то так. Вообщем это бегло выдумана схема.

Можете посоветовать мне какое нибудь достойное Кунг Фу с которого я могу начать ?

Comment: Вы потратили больше времени на написание вопроса, чем на поиск уже существующих.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ох, древности какие .-. Но да, вопрос технически дубликат, а лучших (более актуальных) материалов на русском языке, насколько мне известно, с тех пор не появилось.

Comment: @D-side этот вопрос (и ответ к нему) превратится в точно такую же древность буквально через пол года.

Comment: @PashaPash вообще говоря, уже текущие материалы **уже** устаревшие, когда Rails 5 уже в бете, а последний Ruby версии 2.3 с новинками в синтаксисе. И поскольку на перевод требуется время, улучшения на этом фронте не ожидается :\

Answer (score 1):

Ситуация с книгами по Ruby на русском языке довольно плачевна. Их можно сказать нет, издательства в погоне за популярным Rails, полностью проигнорировали перевод книг по Ruby. В результате рубисты и рельсовики учат язык и фреймворк по английским источникам. Даже если что-то переводится, спросом не пользуется, так как разработчики уже читали это на английском. Издательства делают вывод, что тема не пользуется спросом, поэтому толковых книг на русском очень мало. Русскоязычные читатели не могут продраться к Rails, так как книг по Ruby либо нет, либо очень мало.

### Ruby

1. Флэнаган Д., Мацумото Ю. Язык программирования Ruby.
   Книга от создателя языка Мацумото, последовательное, хотя местами странное изложение. Книга может быть использована для изучения языка.
2. Хэл Фултон, Андрэ Арко. Путь Руби.
   Совершенно новая книга, охватывает Ruby 2.1. Примеры использования языка. Сам Фултон заявляет что изучить язык по его книге невозможно, так как в нем нет систематического изложения языка. В общем, познакомиться можно, досконально выучить – трудно.

На английском, но которую бы желательно прочитать:

3. Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0, 4th edition, Dave Thomas
   Основополагающая книга по Ruby, у которой есть даже нарицательное имя среди рубистов: “Кирко-мотыга”, по изображения на обложке.

Это первичный уровень освоения языка. Далее следует обязательно ознакомиться с книгой по мета-программированию, иначе многие моменты языка могут так и остать для вас черной магией. К сожалению, книга не переведена

4. Paolo Perrotta. Metaprogramming Ruby 2.

Далее можно привести еще список из 10 толковых книг, которые так и не увидели перевода.

### Web-программирование на Ruby

Вы не сможете изучив Ruby тут же создавать сайты. Вам придется дополнительно освоить один из фрейворков. Дело в том, что все современные фреймворки Ruby совместимы между собой через менеджер пакетов bundler, с одной стороны и общий интерфейс взаимодействия с серверами Rack с другой. Поэтому Web-экосистема давно представляет собой большой фрейворк. Есть разные фрейморки Rails, Sinatra, Lotus, но 90% библиотек-гемов совместимы со всеми ими.

Ruby часто называют современным LISP без скобок. Язык хитрый и магичный. Самое интересное, что он позволяет легко, как и символьные языки вроде LISP и Prolog, строить свои собственные DSL-языки вроде RSpec, Cucumber или мощные фреймворки вроде Rails, которые не просто задают архитектуру для Web-приложения, они расширяют язык.

Есть два пути к Web-приложениям на Ruby. Вы начинаете через Rails и изучаете магию, попутно вгрызаясь в Ruby. Или вы учите Ruby, а потом изучаете Rails. Проблема в том, что изучить Ruby, не так просто как может показаться на первый взгляд. Объектно-ориентированное программирование с использованием блоков и миксинов в Ruby, не уступает ООП С++ с его шаблонами, указателями и множественным наследованием. В общем использовать тот же Rails и понимать его – это зачастую разница в несколько лет. Поэтому смотрите как идти к Web-приложениям: есть быстрый путь, сразу начать с Rails, есть медленный и основательный – с Ruby, но результат реально долгий, хотя белых пятен для вас не останется, как это может случиться с рельсовиком.

1. Сэм Руби, Дэйв Томас. Rails 4. Гибкая разработка веб-приложений.

Актульная информация по фрейворку Rails, к чести издательства даже актуализируется

2. [Майкл Хартл. Изучение Rails на Примерах.](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning)

Толковый учебник, который постоянно актуализируется и переводится

3. Оби Фернандес. Путь Rails.

Отличная книга, к сожалению, на русском только по Rails 2 – устарела безбожно, на английском понятно Rails 4 – очень обстоятельное и последовательное изложение фреймворка.

4. Alan Harris, Konstantin Haase. Sinatra: Up and Running

Обязательна для чтения после изучения Rails, дает понимание как работают Ruby-приложения на уровне Rack.

5. David Chelimsky. The RSpec Book.

Тестирование приложений при помощи RSpec. Когда начнете изучать Rails вы поймете почему эта книга обязательна для чтения - создание приложений через тесты, часть философии Rails-сообщества.

Comment: А что можно почитать о сетевом программировании на раби? Не книги про клепание сайтецов, а необходимая теория для написания idle-сканеров, программ для работы с сетевыми протоколами, http-обмен, сокеты.

Comment: 1. По-русски правильно говорить "руби". 2. Да, конечно, ориентируйтесь на книги из первого списка. Плюс дополнительно обратите внимание на фреймворк Sinatra - он ближе к чистому Ruby, скорее всего он вам тоже будет интересен. Это 4-я книга из списка Web-программирования Sinatra: Up and Running

Comment: @cheops я предлагаю вам добавить эту информацию в описание метки `ruby`

Comment: @typemoon для таких задач достаточно понимать сам язык и абстракции этой области. О сетях и ОС книг достаточно, а книги о Ruby описаны выше.

Comment: В этом языке вообще что-то непонятное происходит. Например, когда блок с выражением | x | передается куда-то, каким образом переменной x последовательно присваиваются значения? Например: 9.times {| x | print x}, не уверен насчет правильности. Все скрыто в черных ящиках, и тем, что писал на си и асм такой язык выносит мозг. Здесь все важное для понимания скрыто.

Comment: @typemoon ровно наоборот, скрыто всё неважное. Этот метод выполняет блок указанное количество раз, и ловить аргумент в его блоке это плохой тон; хотя что в нём будет, известно из [документации](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Integer.html#method-i-times). Если хотите обсудить язык, приглашайте в чатик, поболтаем :)

Comment: @typenoon да язык выглядит магически - это его сильная и слабая сторона. Сложную задачу можно решать сложно простыми методами и просто сложными. Ruby местами сложен, но позволяет элегантно решать большое количество задач.

Comment: Sanek Zhitnik, спасибо, за предложение, но лучше немного попозже. Текст слишком эмоциональный для метки. Я просто некоторое время назад со своим издательством переписывался на эту тему, это сжатое изложение моей позиции по Ruby-книгам на русском.