# Посоветуйте книгу по Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать какие книги по Ruby on Rails обязательны к прочтению. Не совсем новичек, но многого не знаю, и есть сомнения по поводу качества кода, который пишу. Так что хочу разобраться с лучшими и полезными практиками по использованию фреймворка.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504831/199934 — развёрнутое аргументированное мнение.

Comment: Спасибо, познавательно!)

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

1. [Путь Ruby](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33512246/) - по самим рельсам.
2. [Совершенный код](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5508646/) - хоть и не по рельсам, но читать обязательно.